# I would like to make my program display the order total/invoice

Tags: python

Here is what ive done:

```
food =["cheeseburger", "smallchips", "drink"]
prices =[2.50, 1.50, 1]
x=0

myorderfood=[]
myordercost=[]

print("Burgers\n")

print("Menu:")
print("Cheeseburger. Cost - $2.50 each")
print("Small chips. Cost - $1.50 each")
print("Drink - Cola only. Cost - $1.00 each\n")
```

I want to display an invoice at the end once the user has completed there order showing there total price.

This is some of my code for just the drinks, same type of code used for cheeseburger etc. :

```
while True:
    try:
        drinkselect = input("Please select which drink:\n")
        if  drinkselect == "cola":
            quantitydrink = int(input("How many would you like?\n"))

    except ValueError:
            print("Not valid")
            continue

    if drinkselect != "cola":
        print("Not on our menu!\n")
    else:
         print("good choice\n")
         break
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? What are you expecting the output to be and what is it?

Comment: @Riceblades well for now, ive written all my code regarding the questioning - as in how many cheese burgers etc. after the user has inputted all of it i want the program to display the total cost

Comment: you have a list for food and a list for prices. How do you know which food item corresponds to which price? I would use a dictionary so you can have key:value pairs, like cheeseburger:2.00. Also, another user (or you?) asked about this same problem earlier. Maybe post the problem you are trying to answer.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman lol it was me, i couldn't edit the post so im on my other acc...

Comment: There isn't enough information here to help you. Post the question you are trying to answer.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman i have updated the post, is this any better>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```py
from statistics import quantiles
from xml.etree.ElementPath import prepare_predicate


food =["cheeseburger", "smallchips", "drink"]
prices =[2.50, 1.50, 1]
x=0
price = 5
quantitydrink = 0
myorderfood=[]
myordercost=[]

print("Burgers\n")

print("Menu:")
print("Cheeseburger. Cost - $2.50 each")
print("Small chips. Cost - $1.50 each")
print("Drink - Cola only. Cost - $1.00 each\n")
print("10% GST applies to total amount (including both food and delivery)")
print("Delivery is free for food orders that are $30 or more")
print("Delivery cost is an additional $5 for food orders below $30\n")
while True:
    try:
        drinkselect = input("Please select which drink:\n")
        if  drinkselect == "cola":
            quantitydrink += int(input("How many would you like?\n"))

    except ValueError:
            print("Not valid")
            continue

    if drinkselect != "cola":
        print("Not on our menu!\n")
    else:
        print("good choice\n")
        price += 1 * quantitydrink
        print(f"Your total cost is {price}!")
        break
```

So the base price is 5 for the delivery and if you pick cola it adds the price of the cola multiplied by the amount you purchase to the price variable.

The += operator is best for this.

**Changes:**

```py
price = 5 #added this on line 8 because the delivery cost is 5 so that is the base price
quantitydrink = 0 #added this on line 9 so you can add the amount to it later in the code
quantitydrink += int(input("How many would you like?\n")) # changed this in line 26 to add the amount you are ordering to the initial value.
price += 1 * quantitydrink # added this in line 36 to calculate the price based on how many colas you are ordering and the base price
print(f"Your total cost is {price}!") #added this at line 37 to print the final price of the order
```

hope this helps!

**FINAL CODE WITH ALL FIXES:**

```py
from statistics import quantiles
from xml.etree.ElementPath import prepare_predicate


finished = False
food =["cheeseburger", "smallchips", "drink", "delivery"]
prices =[2.50, 1.50, 1, 5]
x=0
price = 5
quantitydrink = 0
quantityburger = 0
quantitychips = 0
quantitydelivery = 0

myorderfood=[]
myordercost=[]

print("Burgers\n")

print("Menu:")
print("Cheeseburger. Cost - $2.50 each")
print("Small chips. Cost - $1.50 each")
print("Drink - Cola only. Cost - $1.00 each\n")
print("10% GST applies to total amount (including both food and delivery)")
print("Delivery is free for food orders that are $30 or more")
print("Delivery cost is an additional $5 for food orders below $30\n")

name = input("What is your name?\n")

print("\nHello " + name + "\n")

while finished == False:
    try:
        burgerselect = input("Please select which burger:\n")
        if  burgerselect == "cheeseburger":
            quantityburger += int(input("How many would you like?\n"))            
    except ValueError:
            print("Not valid")
            continue

    if burgerselect != "cheeseburger":
        print("Not on our menu!\n")
    else:
         print("good choice\n")
         price += 2.5 * quantityburger

    try:
        chipselect = input("Please select what size chips:\n")
        if  chipselect == "small":
            quantitychips += int(input("How many would you like?\n"))

    except ValueError:
            print("Not valid")
            continue

    if chipselect != "small":
        print("Not on our menu!\n")
    else:
        print("good choice\n")
        price += 1.50 * quantitychips

    try:
        drinkselect = input("Please select which drink:\n")
        if  drinkselect == "cola":
            quantitydrink += int(input("How many would you like?\n"))

    except ValueError:
            print("Not valid")
            continue

    if drinkselect != "cola":
        print("Not on our menu!\n")
    else:
        print("good choice\n")
        price += 1 * quantitydrink

    deliveryselect=input('Would you like delivery? \n Yes: Delivery\n No: No delivery \n \n')
    if deliveryselect=='Yes'or deliveryselect=='yes':
        print('Thank You\n')
        if price <= 30:
            price += 5
        elif price > 30:
            price += 0
        finished == True
        break
    elif deliveryselect =='No' or deliveryselect=='no':
        print('Thank you\n')
        finished == True
        break

    
print(f"Your total cost is {price}!")
```

Comment: ok this works, but if i have multiple food choices how do i add all of it to one?

Comment: For any other food items just use the price of it multiplied by the quantity `+= price` and it will add to the same variable at the top!

Comment: ok and then once ive done lets say, cheeseburgers and my drinks and chips etc, i want it to display "your total price is", blah blah, so with what you have said how would that be implimented?

Comment: At the end of the code you can print it and use something called an f string and you could just use `print(f"Your total cost is {price}!")` there and you should have no issues!

Comment: ive done it but it got the price wrong it was 8.50 but it says 9

Comment: Could you edit the post to contain your current code or send a github gists link to it. Thanks!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zeroaus/1e08d085159240c482e63a4697fb7152 here you go

Comment: On line 38 you did not change the price per from 1 to 2.5!

Comment: ok, that all works, but now i have a multiple choice question i will show. https://gist.github.com/zeroaus/855ea80bfaa09e75b8614f033bcea877

Comment: I'm assuming you want to add to the price if it's delivery? If that's the case just put if it is yes then `price += amountdeliverycostshere`

Comment: sorry but im unsure how to add it, ive added the vairable and price += * quantitydelivery, but im a bit confused sorry

Comment: Upload the full code to github gists and use comments (in the code) with a #. to show me where the issues are and explain them there.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zeroaus/841c9cc2be93672c74f3ea60f155ed35

Comment: isn't the delivery just a one time consistent payment of $30 or does something change it?

Comment: so if an order is over 30 dollars its free, if not its 5 dollars

Comment: Ohhh sorry I was confused okay give me 1 second

Comment: Tell me if [this](https://gist.github.com/Riceblade/6155fa994dc4054d3b896844dc5a759a) works!

Comment: it works kinda, it repeats itself after saying yes

Comment: This should fix all issues. Tell me if there are any problems [LINK](https://gist.github.com/Riceblade/5503760a69a8e90ad7e751ff2b46db61)